# Подскажите правильный ход решения задачи по SQL-запросу

Tags: mysql, sql

Если у меня в БД есть таблица с полным списком моделей, в таблице t_models, мне нужно вывести только 20 моделей, то для вывода 20 избранных не по-порядку моделей, нужно создать табличку t_models_vip из одного поля ID c 20-мя строками с ID-ами нужных моделей... тогда на вторую вкладку вывожу SELECT t_models.* from t_models INNER JOIN t_models_vip WHERE t_models.ID=t_models_vip.ID; 
То есть выводить только те строки из t_models, для которых есть соответствующий ID в t_models_vip.
Прошу подтвердить или опровергнуть меня(желательно с примерами)? 
Как лучше сделать пожалуйста подскажите, буду очень признателен...

```
    INSERT INTO t_models (id, alias, parent_id, name, logo, descr, status) VALUES 
                         (119, 'ac-cars', 0, 'AC Cars', 'ac-cars.gif', NULL, 1),
```

Comment: Может я неверно понял суть, но не проще ли просто добавить поле `vip int(1)` в `t_models`, которое и будет определять, является ли эта модель vip?

Тогда запрос на вытаскивание будет проще простого: `SELECT * FROM 't_models' WHERE 'vip' > 0`

Comment: Тоже идея правильная, да и возможно даже проще... Пять баллов!

Answer (score 1):

Ответ из комментариев:

Может я неверно понял суть, но не проще ли просто добавить поле `vip int(1)` в `t_models`, которое и будет определять, является ли эта модель `vip`? Тогда запрос на вытаскивание будет проще простого: `SELECT * FROM 't_models' WHERE 'vip' > 0`

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить флаг vip и сделать так: `SELECT * FROM t_models WHERE vip=1 LIMIT 20`
Отдельную копию таблицы создавать совершенно ни к чему

Comment: @Jenssen, почему?